# Utilização de Simpleject com Class Library

Tags: c#

Estou iniciando no uso do simpleject para injeção de dependência.

Criei a classe  BootStrapper para registrar os containers:

```
public class  BootStrapper
{
    public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {

        container.Register<IRepository, Repository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Verify();
    }

}
```

Criei a classe SimpleInjectorInitializer para iniciar as configurações do simpleinject:

```
 public class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();          
        InitializeContainer(container);
        container.Verify();

    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        BootStrapper.RegisterServices(container);
    }
}
```

Na inicialização da classe eu chamo :

```
 SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize();
```

A minha variável está declarada como

```
 private readonly IRepository _Repository;
```

Quando eu vou executar o comando :

```
Console.WriteLine("Teste" + _repository.SelecionarRegistroPorCommando("123"));
```

O compilador informa que não tem instância do objeto.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new TesteIoC();
    }


}

public class TesteIoC
{
    private readonly IRepository _Repository;
    public TesteIoC()
    {
        SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize();
        Console.WriteLine("Teste" + _repository.SelecionarRegistroPorCommando("123"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está testando isso aonde, em um `Console Application`?

Comment: Sim estou usando um console application para testar. Este código que postei é da Class Library e no console application eu estou instânciando a class library.

Comment: Coloque o código completo da sua `Console Application`.

Comment: Virgilio Novic  eu editei a pergunta e coloquei a classe da Console Application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em `console application`, é diferente, você precisa utilizar os comandos dentro da `classe Main` para funcionar. Se for Web pode trabalhar com injeção de dependencia, mas, no seu caso especifico (`Console Application`) não tem nada na [**documentação**](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) que diz que isso funcione, no máximo o que está no código abaixo:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var container = new Container();
            container.Register<IRepository,Repository>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
            container.Verify();

            //instânciado pelo container manualmente
            IRepository rep = container.GetInstance<IRepository>();            

            System.Console.WriteLine("Pression <Enter>");
        }
    }
}
```

Faça os testes, em `ASPNET Web` que vai funcionar igual o que está na [**documentação**](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), ai você tirar todo o proveito desse pacote.